# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have grid-view that loops every row but i am getting this error:

```
The variable name '@UserId' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure
```

I have fixed the connection issue but now i see new issue.  Please help.

```
    protected void btn_App_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                myCmd.Connection = myCon;
                myCon.Open();

                foreach (GridViewRow row in myGV.Rows)
                {

                    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        Label UserId = row.FindControl("lblUsrID") as Label;
                        TextBox Start_Date = row.FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox;

                        TextBox End_Date = row.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;
                        CheckBox Reg_Appr = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("txtchkUsrApp")) as CheckBox;

                        string myUserID = UserId.Text;


                             myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                             myCmd.CommandText = "update myTable set Start_Date = @Start_Date, End_Date = @End_Date, Reg_Appr = @Reg_Appr where UserId = @UserId  ";
                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserId.Text;
                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Start_Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Start_Date.Text;
                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@End_Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = End_Date.Text;

                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Reg_Appr", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Reg_Appr.Checked;   
                             myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                             
                             SendActivationEmail(myUserID);
                    }
               }

                myCon.Close();


            }

       }


    }


    //send email
    private void SendActivationEmail(string myUserID)
    {
        // send email
    }
```

Comment: You have `myCon.Close()` in there twice. It isn't necessary, not even once, since you are wrapping it in a `using` block. In addition, your `foreach` loop should encapsulate your using statements too.

Comment: you have `myCon.Open()` inside the loop and the `Close()` outside. Move the `Open()` outside the loop.

Comment: Also, do you really want `ExecuteNonQuery()` outside the loop? will only update table for last row in GridView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move these statments

```
 myCmd.Connection = myCon;
 myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 myCon.Open();
```

outside the loop.

Then you will only open the connection once, not once for each row.

As per your comments, you also have to do the following:

Below the open statement add the following:

```
var uParm = myCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var sdParm = myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Start_Date", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var edParm = myCmd.Parameters.Add("@End_Date", SqlDbType.VarChar);
var rParm = myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Reg_Appr", SqlDbType.Bit);
```

Then where you had the parameter add statement prior replace with this.

```
uParm.Value = UserId.Text;
sdParm.Value = Start_Date.Text;
edParm.Value = End_Date.Text;
rParm.Value = Reg_Appr.Checked;
```

Comment: thanks, i have followed your suggestion but now i got new error: "The variable name '@UserId' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure". Please see my initial post, i have updated.  thanks

Comment: Hogan, thanks.  I am little bit confused here, don't you need to find the values in the gridview first before you assign the parameters?  can you u post the entire code so i can were you are adding the vars.  thanks

Comment: i just figured out.  all what i had to do is add this: myCmd.Parameters.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

You're opening the connection during each loop. You need to close it before opening it again.

You will likely get an error in the other calls to `Close()`, though, so you need to check the state first to verify the connection is open.

```
if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                    {
                        Label UserId = row.FindControl("lblUsrID") as Label;
                        TextBox Start_Date = row.FindControl("txtStartDate") as TextBox;

                        TextBox End_Date = row.FindControl("txtEndDate") as TextBox;
                        CheckBox Reg_Appr = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("txtchkUsrApp")) as CheckBox;

                        string myUserID = UserId.Text;

                             myCmd.Connection = myCon;
                             myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                             myCon.Open();
                             myCmd.CommandText = "update myTable set Start_Date = @Start_Date, End_Date = @End_Date, Reg_Appr = @Reg_Appr where UserId = @UserId  ";
                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserId.Text;
                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Start_Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Start_Date.Text;
                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@End_Date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = End_Date.Text;

                             myCmd.Parameters.Add("@Reg_Appr", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = Reg_Appr.Checked;                                
                             SendActivationEmail(myUserID);
                             // added this line
                             myCon.Close();
                    }
```